# CSS3 Animation and keep end position

Tags: html, css

I have created an animation which can be seen within the following [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8nu8gfut/). To create the animation I used the following CSS code and HTML CODE:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h2>
    Welcome
    <span>:)</span>
  </h2>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  font-size:28px;
  margin:20px;
}
div span{
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;    
    display:inline-block;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(90deg);
    }
}
```

As can be seen in the demo I rotate the smiley. What I trying to achieve is that the smileys stays at its last position. Does anyone know how I could solve this without using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```css
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```